# ANT Warning: please use webxml attribute to war task

Tags: ant, war

I am getting this warning even though i am using webxml in my ANT task

here is my ANT file

```
<project name="start" basedir="./">

    <property name="web.dir" value="war"/>
    <property name="name" value="start"/>

    <target name="package" description="Packaging Start WAR">
        <war destfile="${name}.war" webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.*"/>
        </fileset>
        </war>
    </target>

</project>
```

Am i missing something. Even though when war is being created, it copies appropriate **web.xml** in it. but why i am getting this as *WARNING*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This discussion](http://www.coderanch.com/t/107424/tools/war-task-gives-warnings) is related to your problem.

This should fix the warning (I haven't tried it though).  Essentially `exclude` `web.xml` from the `fileset`, since this is being specified in `webxml` attribute.

```
<property name="web.dir" value="war"/>
<property name="name" value="start"/>

<target name="package" description="Packaging Start WAR">
    <war destfile="${name}.war" webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
    <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.*"/>
        <exclude name="**/web.xml"/>
    </fileset>
    </war>
</target>
```